# Replacing values with piping in R

Tags: indexing, magrittr

I am trying to see if piping can be useful here -

```
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==1), "blockType"] <- 0
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==2), "blockType"] <- 0
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==3), "blockType"] <- 1
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==4), "blockType"] <- 1

p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==1), "trialType"] <- 0
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==2), "trialType"] <- 1
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==3), "trialType"] <- 0
p3Data[which(p3Data$memCond==4), "trialType"] <- 1
```

How can I use %>% and make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(magrittr)
p3Data <- data.frame(memCond=sample(4,10,replace=TRUE))
p3Data <- p3Data %>% transform(blockType = (memCond-1) %/% 2, trialType = (memCond+1) %% 2)
# memCond blockType trialType
# 1        4         1         1
# 2        1         0         0
# 3        3         1         0
# 4        2         0         1
# 5        3         1         0
# 6        4         1         1
# 7        1         0         0
# 8        2         0         1
# 9        3         1         0
# 10       4         1         1
```

With the latest version of the package you should be able to do even better with

```
p3Data %<>% transform(blockType = (memCond-1) %/% 2, trialType = (memCond+1) %% 2)
```

but I couldn't test it